# The symmetry of the isotropic cartesian tensor of Newtonian fluid

Tags: tensors, fluid-dynamics

I'm trying to prove the symmetry of the isotropic tensor in the linear relation between the shear stress and strain rate for Newtonian fluid
$$T_{ij}=\beta_{ijlm}\frac{\partial u_{l}}{\partial x_{m}}.$$
My attempt is based on the assumption that the shear stress vanishes for pure rotation, that is
$$\beta_{ijlm}\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial u_{l}}{\partial x_{m}}+\frac{\partial u_{m}}{\partial x_{l}}\right)+\beta_{ijlm}\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial u_{l}}{\partial x_{m}}-\frac{\partial u_{m}}{\partial x_{l}}\right)=0,$$
since there is no elongation, we get
$$\beta_{ijlm}\left(\frac{\partial u_{l}}{\partial x_{m}}-\frac{\partial u_{m}}{\partial x_{l}}\right)=0.$$
Does this imply the symmetry of $\beta_{ijlm}$?